# UIButton only setimage on UIControlStateNormal

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a simple UIButton question

I need to show an image on a button only if it is in UIControlStateNormal and not show it if I click on it.

Here's my code:

```
[cardButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cardBack.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and when a button is clicked, I will change its state:

```
cardButton.selected = card.isFaceUp;
```

Now the problem is, even the button's state is switched to UIControlStateSelected, the image is still there...

I have checked the imageForState method and surprisingly found that `[cardButton imageForState:UIControlStateSelected]` returns the same value as `[cardButton imageForState:UIControlStateNormal]`

I never set the image value for selected state anywhere and have no idea what happened here.

Need your help! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instances of `UIButton` use the "normal" state titles, images, and background images for the other states if no other states are explicitly set, and (annoyingly) even if you explicitly try to set these properties to `nil` for the other states.  What I usually do is create a one pixel clear image and use that for the other states, like:

```
[cardButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clear"] forState:UIControlStateSelected]
```

Another thing you've got to watch out for is that the states `UIControlStateSelected` and `UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted` are actually distinct, so if you don't want your normal state artwork to show up when the user taps and holds the *currently selected* button, you need to also set:

```
[cardButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clear"] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted]
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for me. Good job for pointing out setting nil won't work for other states.

Comment: However, I am still wondering if there is a more general way of implementing this. Otherwise, I need to set the clear image for all other states if I only need to use my first image for normal state.

Comment: @zeroliu: I usually have real artwork (not the clear pixel hack thing) for at least the normal and highlighted states.  And the other state flags (selected, disabled, and "application") are used less frequently, so I've only had to use the clear pixel trick a couple of times.  It is pretty irritating though.

Answer (score 1):

This is a work around without using a 1 pixel image:

```
    if (!cardButton.isSelected && cardButton.isEnabled){
        [cardButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cardback.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else{
        [cardButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

I suppose if you are trying to create an app which needs to be published in the app store you'll want the more elegant solution of the 1 pixel transparent image.

Answer (score 0):

try following line of code?

```
[cardButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: Aaron explained the reason in his answer.